# Cleaning up state on useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, state, resource-cleanup

Can someone give me a light on what may be happening here? I have an effect that basically, when I load a product page it updates an state with an array of items, but when I change the product (a prop) it's not cleaning up my state. The code is below, can someone see what may be missing?

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState<any>([]);
useEffect(() => {
    if (product) {
      handleCartArray(product.name, variant.sku, variant.price, product.productId);
    }
    return () => {
      console.log('is this running?');

      cleanCartItems();
    };
  }, [product]);

  function cleanCartItems() {
    console.log('I am trying to clean the cart items');
    setCartItems([]);
  }
```

Not really much to be added here. I am trying to clean up this state everytime a new product is loaded, but it isn't working.

Comment: Can you share the way you defined "product"? In case it is a plain variable, converting it to a state variable may solve the problem you are facing. In any case, please let me whether or not the change worked if/when you make the change.

Comment: Please read how to make a [mre]. Leaving out relevant parts of your code makes it much harder for people to help and forces them to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your *useEffect* hook is running (you haven't explained what ***product*** is, so I'm not even sure it's running).
Also how about calling **setCartItems([])** inside the the return statement in *useEffect* itself? The arrow statement is a function itself, right now it's literally a function only being used to callback another function.

Comment: Yeah, thought of the same -- calling setCartItems([]) within useEffect but decided not to follow through with that thought as the code is most probably, as it should be, an MRE. But in any case, that would be a good move.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the replies. Actually yea, I didn't put what product is, it's actually a prop, passed by when a product is selected on a store front. So, to be sure, I've added the console.logs and all of them run (I mean, the product changes and the  'I am trying to clean the cart items' shows up, but the setCartItems([]) appears to be not running. I am updating the question with the latest code and the console as well

Comment: @SuryasishPaul Didn't thought of that, thank you for the comment!

Comment: @FelipeLemos Not sure why that's happening but maybe this can prove useful?
[The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877875/20717109)

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` dependencies only fire up the code within when the `state` of one/all of the dependencies changes. In your case `product` seems like a simple variable. Define product using `useState` or some centralised state management system and your useEffect will work perfectly. Good luck!